# How to configure default environment to propagated to all containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have added the environment variables under the `docker.service.d` and reloaded , restarted the docker service on the machine but when i logged into the container, those environment variables are not propagated to containers (i was unable to view those env values). Can i please know if there any additional steps needed to be added.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to configure default environment to propagate environment to containers is recorded in [configure-the-docker-client](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client):

> 1. On the Docker client, create or edit the file ~/.docker/config.json in
>    the home directory of the user that starts containers. Add JSON
>    similar to the following example. Substitute the type of proxy with
>    httpsProxy or ftpProxy if necessary, and substitute the address and
>    port of the proxy server. You can also configure multiple proxy
>    servers simultaneously.
>
>    You can optionally exclude hosts or ranges from going through the
>    proxy server by setting a noProxy key to one or more comma-separated
>    IP addresses or hosts. Using the * character as a wildcard for hosts
>    and using CIDR notation for IP addresses is supported as shown in this
>    example:
>
>    ```
>    {
>     "proxies":
>     {
>       "default":
>       {
>         "httpProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
>         "httpsProxy": "http://192.168.1.12:3128",
>         "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8"
>       }
>     }
>    }
>    ```
>
>    Save the file.
> 2. When you create or start new containers, the environment variables are set automatically within the container.

**Check the default environment after set `config.json`:**

```
~$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=6ca0f86604ea
TERM=xterm
HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.1.12:3128
https_proxy=http://192.168.1.12:3128
NO_PROXY=*.test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8
no_proxy=*.test.example.com,.example2.com,127.0.0.0/8
HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.1.12:3128
http_proxy=http://192.168.1.12:3128
HOME=/root
```